# C socket multiple local ips

Tags: c, linux, sockets

We have **N** local ip's on our server.
I need to create socket connection using one of them.
How can i do that ?

```
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)addr, sizeof(*addr));
// ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bind()` the socket to the appropriate local address before connecting.