# C DNS query using one of multiple local ips

Tags: c, linux, dns

We have multiple local IPs on our system. We need to perform DNS queries (MX, NX lookup) using one of the many local IPs.

How can I do that? For example, I found the functions `res_init` and `res_send`, but they can't do that. Any suggestions?

As I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937511/c-socket-multiple-local-ips) it, I need to use the `bind` function to attach a socket to one of the local IPs. Do I have to use `getaddrinfo` for the DNS lookup?

Answer (score 1):

To do DNS lookup, you use `getaddrinfo`.

[Here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo)'s the manpage, and [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html)'s an awsome UNIX/Linux/Winsock programming guide that I use. Great section on `getaddrinfo`, and just about everything else.

Comment: it didn't answer my question at all. link to man page is not a answer. how do i get MX/NS record using getaddinfo using specific local ip?

Comment: @twoface88: That's not what your question reads as. Your question reads as "Do I have to use the `getaddrfino` function to DNS lookup". If that is not your question, I'm sorry, but I have to admit, I don't even know what MX/NS lookup is.